# Thread block clusters: What happens if the number of possible concurrent blocks is not divisible by cluster size?

Tags: cuda

The H100 GPU has 132 SMs. Now assume the cluster size is 5, and due to resource limitations only 1 thread block fits on a SM.

The programming guide states

> Similar to how threads in a thread block are guaranteed to be co-scheduled on a streaming multiprocessor, thread blocks in a cluster are also guaranteed to be co-scheduled on a GPU Processing Cluster (GPC) in the GPU

Does this guarantee of co-scheduling imply that only 130 SMs will be used?
Or will the last 2 SMs also be used and the remaining 3 blocks of the cluster will be scheduled later to the same GPC? (cluster.sync() would the need to block until there is enough room in the GPC for the other 3 blocks)

Comment: First, I don't think its a given how many SM will be used overall, just because 5 divides evenly into 130.  Second, the guarantee of co-scheduling implies that the cluster will not be scheduled until sufficient resources are available to schedule all the blocks in the cluster.  Anything else (partial scheduling) could lead to a hang.